# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I am new in Python.
I have 2 Dict and 1 List and will be process on recapitulation method.

```
 system_list= ['cassandra', 'flume', 'hbase', 'hdfs', 'mapreduce', 'zookeeper']

allaspects= {'flume': [19.0, 13, 46, 5, 100, 0, 6, 6, 0], 
 'hdfs': [161.0, 221.0, 232.5, 8.0, 60.0, 7.5, 16, 70, 10], 
 'zookeeper': [40.0, 66, 67, 13, 36, 1.5, 2, 19.5, 6], 
 'mapreduce': [161, 23, 11, 79, 41, 6.5, 8.5, 101.5, 8],
 'hbase': [270.75, 573, 264, 197, 426, 7.0, 12.5, 91, 4], 
 'cassandra': [404, 453, 287, 17, 307, 1.0, 10, 31, 26]}

allaspects_big= {'flume': [18.0, 119.0, 43.0, 3.5, 81.0, 0, 6.0, 4.5, 0], 
 'hdfs': [152.5, 214.0, 221.5, 7.0, 56.0, 6.0, 14, 68, 10], 
 'zookeeper': [33, 55, 56, 13, 28, 1.0, 1, 16.0, 3.5], 
 'mapreduce': [152, 219, 106, 71, 34, 6.5, 7.5, 91.0, 7.0],
 'hbase': [227, 505, 233, 170, 320, 6.0, 12.5, 84, 4], 
 'cassandra': [195, 271, 177, 10.5, 156, 1.0, 6, 16, 20]}



def recapitulation(system_list, total):
  count = {}
  msg =""
  # print total
  for system in system_list:
    count[system] = 0
    for data in total[system]:
      count[system] = count[system] + data
    msg= msg+""+system+"("+str(int(count[system]))+")"
    if(system == 'zookeeper'):
      msg= msg+"."
    else:
      msg= msg+", "
  return msg
```

I put all of my script in the same file. 
If I run only one dict (execute only a3 or only a3b in my case) the method give us the string output. But When I run the a3 and a3b( see at the below) together. I get the error 'str' has no attribute.

```
a3 = recapitulation(system_list ,allaspects) 
a3b = recapitulation(system_list, allaspects_big)
```

Error:

```
a3b = recapitulation(system_list, allaspects_big) 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'allaspects_big'
```

Full traceback:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "py/parse-all.py", line 2537, in <module>
>     a3b = recapitulation(system_list, a3.allaspects_big) 
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'allaspects_big'
> ```

I don't have idea to solve this. Please give me suggestion. what's wrong with my scripts. Thanks!

Comment: That code would not give that error. You need to show the *exact* error message plus the *full* traceback.

Comment: I have update my post and add full traceback of errors message.

I guess, this is about `msg= msg+""+system+"("+str(int(count[system]))+")"` . but not hundred percents sure about it.

Comment: That traceback shows *different* code than what you posted: you are calling `a3.allaspects_big`, not just `allaspects_big`. Please update your code to what you actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not consistent with the traceback. You say you're running:

```
a3b = recapitulation(system_list, allaspects_big)
```

but the traceback clearly shows:

```
a3b = recapitulation(system_list, a3.allaspects_big) 
                                # ^ what?!
```

`a3` is a string, as returned by `recapitulation`. It therefore *does not* have an `allaspects_big` attribute. I think you just wanted to pass `allaspects_big`, so remove the `a3.` to make the code you're actually running into what you claim you are.

Comment: yes, we can ignore the a3. a3 is my another file which I put the dictionary.

Comment: @indi60 wrong; `a3` is the string returned by `recapitulation(system_list, allaspects)`, as per the assignment you make.

Comment: exactly, the problems is about `a3` thanks for pointing my mistake @jonrsharpe.